# Blender Reflection Plane Subsurface Lighting? (3.0.1) (Eevee)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection, subsurface-scattering

[image]
Hi, I'm trying to get these lamps to show their subsurface lighting in the reflections. How do I do this? I was also trying to get a mirror to reflect into the window reflections, however it just shows up as gray in the reflection. How can I do this? I'm using Blender 3.0.1 in Eevee.
Also, if I do the opposite, and set Light Threshold to a low value, it does this:
[image: Image2]
How can I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean _subsurface_ or _transmission_?

Comment: I'm fairly certain I mean subsurface, how the material lets light through it. There is no transmission applied to the material.

Comment: Subsurface allows light to "penetrate" a surface a certain distance (governed both by the subsurface depth and the RGB radius values) and "bounce around", illuminating areas and spreading colors before ultimately bouncing back out. The best example I think of is shining a flashlight through your hand - your hand will glow red but will have a hard time illuminating anything. Transmission, on the other hand, is more like a slider on how much light passes _straight through_ a surface (bent only by the objects refraction, but not scattered within). Try using some transmission.

Comment: That didn't do anything unfortunately.

Comment: The lamp reflections in the windows are still unlit.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Any ideas then?

Comment: Hey - sorry, I was out for the day. It's hard to tell without seeing your project - there are a lot of variables to consider - distance from light to reflective surface - brightness of light source - thickness of lamp material - subsurface, transmission, alpha, etc... I will add, though that when I render something like a lampshade - I use an emission texture - there are some situations where you might want an ultra-realistic transmission of light, but a lamp simply conveys direct light - there is no real "detail" to it - you don't have to focus on recreating it super accurately.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yeah. It works with emission, but I want it to with this. It's the light source inside of the lamp, making the lamp glow. I just want to have the lamp glow in the glass.